# Remote Content with Links in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of Bootstrap modal windows on a site I'm working on that are loading remote content. This is working perfectly. However, my boss has informed me that the links within those modals cannot go to a new page, they must reload in the modal window.

I have tried a few things with no luck.

First, I have the modal link inside the modal

```
<a data-toggle='modal' class='modalBox' data-target='#largeModal'
href='link here'>Link</a>
```

This link does not work, Bootstrap.js throws this error..

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.preventDefault()')
```

So I tried changing the Id to a different modal window I have on the page and it does pop up behind the modal window that is already there. Which is not exactly what I need, but is promising.

Is there a way around this so the content can load in the same modal window?

Comment: I should elaborate and say that error is coming from bootstrap.min and not any code I have written

Comment: Does i got you right? You have an (opened) modal, containing one or more links. On a click on one of these links you want the content of the modal (that is everything in `<div class="modal">...</div>`) replaced with the linked page? What about resizing the modal after the load? Necessary?

Comment: I suggest to always use the unminified version of vendor libraries during development. This way you can check and track where and why the error occurs.

Comment: @DirkLachowski Yes, I want the div to replaced with the new page. Any why would I want to resize it?

Comment: @Tsunamis I am using the unmagnified version, but its not giving a line number and even still how would that help me here? I don't want to edit bootstraps code.

Comment: Using an iframe inside the modal window is an option?

Comment: @Chevi How would I go about doing this? I'm already loading remote content using the modal and am reusing that modal code throughout the page because it's dynamic.

Comment: @zazvorniki it might require too much refactoring, but an iframe inside the modal window would ensure that all links are opened inside it.

Comment: @Chevi I understand where you are going with the iframe, but with the content I already have coming into the modal window how would I load them into an iframe?

Comment: @zazvorniki I haven't looked much into it, or I would have posted as an answer. But this seems to do a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073618/using-bootstrap-3-0-modals-to-load-dynamic-remote-content-within-an-iframe

Comment: @Chevi I have read that post previously and they are speaking of videos in particular and I am talking about whole webpages lading with links in them.

Comment: I'm aware, but the answer by KayakDave loads URLs (in his example videos, yes) inside the iframe. It should work as well with normal website urls. And once loaded all links within will keep on loading on the iframe. It actually looks good for your needs.

Comment: @Chevi It does not work. One, I am loading content from other pages using href on the clickable element which replaces all content within the modal body. Two if I replace the href with the data-src then then iframe shows up, but is completely blank. You can test this by going to their fiddle and replacing the youtube link with google.

Comment: @zazvorniki If you open your browsers debug console you should see the line number of the error thrown by bootstrap. Then you can read the bootstrap code and try to understand what produced this error. You should of course not edit the bootstrap code, but maybe you can find the reason for the error and alter your code or maybe even find a bug in bootstrap and report it.

Answer (score 5):

As @Chevi suggested, the best option will be to place an iframe inside the modal. There is no need to change your existing page/modal layout as you can insert a new iframe on each klick.

Given you have a bootstrap modal with a link inside the `.modal-body` you will need something like this:

```
$('.modal').on("click", "a", function (e) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.modal-body').html('');
    $('<iframe>').attr('src', target).appendTo($('.modal-body'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This grabs the `href` of the clicked link, replaces the `.modal-body` content with an iframe and sets the iframe's `src` to the href of the link.

Be aware that the link target must be frameable: No framekillers, no X-Frame-Options (therefore linking to google this way will not work!)

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/445eA/

Comment: I'm using this method in a site as as I needed to accomplish what the original question asked. It's definitely the best option for this task in my opinion given the navigation constraints.

Comment: Follow-up question: how would you deal with links inside the modal that have data-toggle="modal"? It currently dismisses the dialog for unknown reasons, even with this patch. I need those links to be that way since pages can both be requested separately or via dialog.

Comment: @afilina Could you ask this as a new question and link to that from here, please? (See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/1686330 )

Answer (score 0):

Onclick call javascript function

```
<a onclick="loadContent()">Link</a>
```

Call Javascript function to load data using ajax request:

```
function loadContent()
{
//You can load data using ajax request
$("#modelBodyId").html('Data')
// If you want to open other modal - $('#largeModal").modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to *assume* you have jQuery available to you, and that all links in the modals are standard anchor tags (`<a href="...">Link</a>`)

I'm also going to assume the modal structure as defined here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

The simplest way to do this is to configure delegates on the links, prevent default, and to load the content in the modal body element. This will require the fewest modifications to the modal content, avoids isolating the content in iframes (therefore breaking styling), and generally is pretty clean solution:

```
jQuery('body').delegate('click', '.modal-body a', function(evt){
    //prevent the browser from navigating to the url for the 'a'
    evt.preventDefault();
    //find the parent that is the "modal-body" of this link
    //load the href html into that parent.
    $(this).parent('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

The above only needs to be run one time, on page ready, and this will handle all existing and future modals. One caveat is that if the links go to an anchor, rather than a new page, this will not work (i.e. `#somepointinapage`), but for most cases it'll work well.

Comment: OPs constraint is to open content linked from the content in the modal in the same modal. Your solution will discard the modal on any click on a link in this modal.

Comment: @DirkLachowski I see, I said ".on" rather than "delegate" - if this is what you meant, feel free to edit the answer next time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i have adopted.
It works with:

- jQuery v1.11.2
- jQuery Migrate v1.2.1
- Bootstrap v3.3.1

Main page HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>

<!-- Your code here -->

</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="/page-1" data-target="bs-modal-lg" class="modal-trigger" data-toggle="modal">Modal page #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/page-2" data-target="bs-modal-md" class="modal-trigger" data-toggle="modal">Modal page #2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-md" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myMediumModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Javascript here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Modal page #1 HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Modal page #1</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul>       
        <li><a href="/" target="_parent">Main page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page-2" data-target="bs-modal-md">Modal page #2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Modal page #2 HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Modal page #2</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul>       
        <li><a href="/" target="_parent">Main page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page-1" data-target="bs-modal-lg">Modal page #1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 3 Modal Vertically Centered (see here http://codepen.io/ahliang85/pen/aFteG/):

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        adjustModalMaxHeightAndPosition : function(focus) {
            $('.modal').each(function(){
              if($(this).hasClass('in') == false){
                $(this).show();
              };
              var contentHeight = $(window).height() - 60;
              var headerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 2;
              var footerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 2;

              $(this).find('.modal-content').css({
                'max-height': function () {
                  return contentHeight;
                }
              });

              $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
                'max-height': function () {
                  return (contentHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight));
                }
              });

              $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({
                'margin-top': function () {
                  return -($(this).outerHeight() / 2);
                },
                'margin-left': function () {
                  return -($(this).outerWidth() / 2);
                }
              });
              if($(this).hasClass('in') == false){
                $(this).hide();
              };
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(window).resize($.adjustModalMaxHeightAndPosition).trigger("resize");
```

Javascript:

```
(function($) {
    $('.modal-trigger').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');    
        var target = $(this).data('target');

        $('.' + target + ' .modal-content').load(href, function(result){
            $('.' + target).modal({show:true});
            $('.' + target).on('loaded.bs.modal', $.adjustModalMaxHeightAndPosition());
        });
    });

    $('.modal').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');        
        var target = $(this).data('target');

        $('.' + target + ' .modal-content').html('').load(href, function(result){
            $('.' + target).on('loaded.bs.modal', $.adjustModalMaxHeightAndPosition());
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here http://naturarisponde.it you can see a working example by clicking on "Privacy Policy" and "Cookie Policy" at the bottom of page.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you have given us a very informative answer, we would rather like something that can adapt to most situations, while being concise and to the point. Also, please don't place links, as they can expire or outdate themselves. Thank You!

Comment: Ok thanks @Zizouz212, it's one of my first answers; i will try to improve in the coming..

Answer (score -1):

Just copy paste the code given bellow. You can also change the site to which it is redirected by changing the link in object and embed tag. This can also be done by using iframe instead of embed. Post if you have any further doubts on this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
    <html lang="en">   
    <head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <title>Modal Window Example</title>   
    <meta name="description" content="Modal Window example using twitter bootstrap">  
    <link href="twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <script src="twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container">  
            <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
            <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;  max-height: 700px; width:800px;">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
                    <h3></h3>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  

                </div> 
                <object data=http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6823/14/27/abstract width="800 px" height="900 px"> 
                    <embed http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6823/14/27/abstract width="800 px" height="900 px"> </embed> 
                    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. 
                </object> 
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
                    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
                </div>  
            </div>
            <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a></p>  
        </div>  


    </body>  
    </html>
```

You have to include bootstrap-modal.js and bootstraps jquery.js file. which you can get from getbootstrap.com