# Unable to close bootstrap3 modal when loading iframe as content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 3 modal.

Following is my code.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <iframe src="remote.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Now every thing works like it should except when the modal is triggered I am unable to hide the modal(even with the close button).

Howwever when I use the modal without iframe the modal functions perfectly.

This has been eating my time for sometime, it would be great if someone could help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

From KayakDave's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818030/2576805

2) Add some jquery that is triggered when the modal dialog button is clicked. The following code expects a link destination in a data-src attribute and for the button to have a class modalButton. And optionally you can specify data-width and data-height- otherwise they default to 400 and 300 respectively (of course you can easily change those).

The attributes are then set on the  which causes the iframe to load the specified page.

```
$('a.modalButton').on('click', function(e) {
var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
var height = $(this).attr('data-height') || 300;
var width = $(this).attr('data-width') || 400;

$("#myModal iframe").attr({'src':src,
                           'height': height,
                           'width': width});
});
```

3) add the class and attributes to the modal dialog's anchor tag:

```
<a class="modalButton" data-toggle="modal" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Oc8sWN_jNF4?rel=0&wmode=transparent&fs=0" data-height=320 data-width=450 data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>
```

---

In the jsFiddle provided at the bottom of the answer, the modal is able to be opened and closed without issue.